# double click on userform running slow excel vba

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I have this code for picking items with multiple values from userform and inserting them into a sheet. The code works perfect on my computer, which is pretty decent. But on a computer from work it runs very slowly, maybe because I'm abusing the "select" method. I ran out of ideas.

```
Sub LSTART_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean) 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo ERR1:
    L = LSTART.List(LSTART.ListIndex, 0)
    Sheets("CONCAT").Select
    Range("A2").Select

    While ActiveCell.Value <> "" And ActiveCell.Value <> Val(L) And ActiveCell.Value <> L
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Wend

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select 
    CODART = ActiveCell.Value

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select   
    CODCLR = ActiveCell.Value

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select      
    TALLE = ActiveCell.Value

    Sheets("ventas").Select

    Range("B11").Select 

    While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 
    Wend                                
    
  ActiveCell.Value = CODART
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = CODCLR 
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = TALLE 
  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 

ERR1:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 

End Sub
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions to optimize your code:

Avoid Selecting Ranges:
Instead of selecting ranges and then working with them, directly reference the ranges and cells. This helps to avoid the overhead associated with selecting cells.

Replace:

```
Sheets("CONCAT").Select
Range("A2").Select
```

with:

```
Dim concatSheet As Worksheet
Set concatSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CONCAT")
CODART = concatSheet.Range("A2").Value
```

Use With Statements:
Utilize the With statement to work with ranges efficiently without repeating the sheet reference.

Replace:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select 
CODART = ActiveCell.Value

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select   
CODCLR = ActiveCell.Value

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select      
TALLE = ActiveCell.Value
```

with:

```
With ActiveCell
    CODART = .Value
    CODCLR = .Offset(0, 1).Value
    TALLE = .Offset(0, 2).Value
End With
```

Minimize the Use of Loops:
Avoid using loops when not necessary. In your case, you can directly work with ranges and cells without the need for a loop.

Replace:

```
While ActiveCell.Value <> "" And ActiveCell.Value <> Val(L) And ActiveCell.Value <> L
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Wend
```

with:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set foundCell = concatSheet.Columns(1).Find(Val(L), LookIn:=xlValues)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
    ' Your logic here
End If
```

These suggestions aim to reduce the reliance on selecting cells and looping through them, which should improve the performance of your code. Adjustments may be needed based on your specific requirements.

Tips:

- Always Declare variables with their respective types,
- Avoid using ActiveCell as it heads overhead to code
- Avoid using .Select multiple times specifically in Loops
- Refer Sheets/Ranges with fully qualifiable reference and use this variable in the code instead of referring the worksheet name every time.

I hope that helps!

Comment: I came back to code review after a very long time and didn't notice that I was on code review instead of StackOverflow. Added the code review instead of new code itself.

Comment: Welcome back. Now it looks good.  +1 :)